# Probability of college acceptance

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

If the probability of me getting accepted into one college is .80, at a second .80, and at a third one .80, what is the probability I’ll get accepted into exactly one of them?

I don’t know if this counts as a separate question, but what is the probability I’ll get accepted into at least one of them, meaning one or more?

Can you also say what formulas you used to find these 2 probabilities?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This feels binomial. Let X have distribution Binomial(3, 0.8). You want $P(X = 1)$.

Comment: I’m assuming that’s for exactly one? 

What would the probability for one or more acceptances be? Thanks

Comment: As stated, this cannot be solved. Usually, the way to do this for problems like this is to assert that the three probabilities are independent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if the choices made are independent of each other (i.e. the choice one of the colleges makes has no influence on the others) the probabilities would be independent right? What would the formula be in that case. Thanks.

Comment: The notion of “influence” is a bit vague. Independence just means “If I know the results of colleges $B$ and $C,$ the probability of college $A$ accepting you is still $0.8.$ You can get dependence without one college “influencing” another.

Comment: Probability for at least one acceptance is $1-\text{probability of no acceptances}$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the college decisions are independent of each other (which is not true in real life but we simplify the problem)

The probability at least one college accepts you is $1-P(\text{no accept})$ which is
$$
1-\left(.2\right)^3 = .992
$$

The chance that exactly one college accepts you is $3$ times the probability one takes you times the probability that the other decline you. We multiply by $3$ to signify that any of the $3$ could accept us
$$
3(.8)(.2)^2 = .096
$$